# WorkbookQuery workaround for older versions of Excel (pre-2016)

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Would there be a simple workaround for functions such as:
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count, .Delete, .Add such that I could easily migrate code written for VBA Excel 2016 to work in older versions?

Take a simple code snippet for example:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Item(i).Name = itemToMatch Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=itemToMatch, Formula:=Formula
```

How would I code this in 2013 or older versions?

Thank you in advance and thank you especially to @D_Bester for all his contributions in the specific area of VBA database coding.

Comment: does [this](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2013/05/02/counting-query-tables-in-excel/) help ?

Comment: I am not sure .... so you can just replace ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count with ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count? Perhaps someone who is more familiar with this stuff can shed some light.